# How do I embed a video in a tweet?

Tags: video, twitter, embed

I recently signed up for Twitter at a client's request. When posting my video's URL or direct link to the .mp4 on Twitter, I'm just getting the link.

When attempting the same with youtube, there is a dropdown "view video" tab.
Is there specific headers that are needing to be sent? I can't find it in the API or on Google. Or any question asked on here about it!

Or is the site needing to be whitelisted by Twitter themselves?

Comment: Wow somebody downvoted this 2 years later....

Answer (score 4):

This question is rather old, but it has quite a few views, and none of the solutions are correct.

Twitter has a feature called [Twitter Cards](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started) that will allow you to have the videos on your website embedded directly in tweets. You will need to add a Player Card to your website via meta data if you would like to achieve this.

Implementing Twitter Cards only requires adding a few lines of code to your HTML head. You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/cards-player-samples). I'll paste one example for your convenience:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ..

        <meta name="twitter:card" content="player">
        <meta name="twitter:site" content="@rchoi">
        <meta name="twitter:title" content="Sample Player Card">
        <meta name="twitter:description" content="This is a sample video. When you implement, make sure all links are secure.">
        <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://yoursite.com/example.png">
        <meta name="twitter:player" content="https://yoursite.com/container.html">
        <meta name="twitter:player:width" content="480">
        <meta name="twitter:player:height" content="480">
        <meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="https://yoursite.com/example.mp4">
        <meta name="twitter:player:stream:content_type" content="video/mp4">

        ..
    </head>

    ..

</html>
```

Not all of the `meta` properties are required. You can find a list of them on Twitter's developer website: [Player Card Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/player#Reference).

You will also need to get your Twitter account whitelisted for Twitter Cards. You can do so at the [Card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator). Once you preview your card, a button should appear, giving you the option to request access to Twitter Cards.

Answer (score 2):

Use http://tinyurl.com/  and put in the url of your YouTube video it will give you a smaller url and tweet that

Comment: I'm trying to inline embed a custom video player, so a youtube url wouldn't help all to much.

Comment: This is the only way you can post a video on twitter, it is not facebook just 140 chars of text can be posted to a post on twitter

Comment: Tried your approach, I know what you're trying to say but it's not what I'm trying to achieve. You can always post a youtube link in twitter anyways as the link will never exceed 140 characters

Comment: It is not possible to add a custom mp4 url to a tweet and expect twitter to parse it into a video, you need to use a service for that or just upload your video to twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you should [directly upload your video to Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172128), from app or web.

Note, there are some restrictions, most notably:

- maximum 140 seconds;
- must be mp4+AAC;
- your browser must have Flash enabled, or the button "Add photos or video" will just be "Add photos" and video upload will fail.

The reason for the latter is probably that after uploading the video you get a small editing (cropping) dialog, which presumably requires Flash.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a nice feature. This question is asking how to embed external videos though