# Upload video on twitter

Tags: android, video, twitter, upload

I have to upload a video on twitter from android app. I have successfully uploaded image and text on twitter. I am using the `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar` library.

I tried uploading video using the same method I used for images, but failed to upload and got exception code `403` and TwitterException `{exceptionCode=[2ea3c142-58dea759], statusCode=403, message=Error creating status., code=189, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.3}`.

I also downloaded twitvid sdk from http://twitvid.pbworks.com/w/page/22556292/Client%20Libraries, but even after integrating this sdk, I could not upload video on twitter.

As per twitter official discusion thread https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11241 we can upload video using twitvid using that code.

Since I am not having a suitable sdk, I am not able to work on this.
Any help to upload video on twitter from android app will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I embed a video in a tweet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731011/how-do-i-embed-a-video-in-a-tweet)

Comment: Its 2.6 years old question

Comment: ...with an up to date answer, unlike this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 2016:** This answer is outdated. Twitter now support video upload in addition to linking.

You cannot upload video directly to Twitter - they simply don't support it.

Here's what you have to do, instead.

1. Upload the video to a 3rd party service (like YouTube)
2. Get the public URL of the uploaded video
3. Add the URL to the status you send to Twitter - e.g. "Here is my video http://example.com/video123"

If you want, you can add a thumbnail of the video as an image attachment.

Comment: they have upload media api, are you sure twitter doesn't support video upload

Comment: My answer is two years old! Things have changed since then.

Comment: Is there any other process for sharing the video to twitter

Comment: Use the Twitter Media APIs.
See Link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/uploading-media

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [CLICK HERE](https://github.com/Kovartthan/TwitterVideoShare) Twitter video share this may be useful to others . I have made up a library by extending twitter4j library . Note this is used for only Silent Video share i.e Without using the composer .

Comment: This is an old question, around 4 years old.

Comment: Yes but this library helps you to share video without using composer in twitter in android

Comment: ok. It will help those who are working on video uploading now. (y)