# How to upload a video to twitter in android application?

Tags: android, video, twitter, upload

I have searched a lot for sending videos to twitter using android application. But I could not get solution. Please help me how to upload video to twitter using android application? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you agree to same, then please mark it accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload video on twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681924/upload-video-on-twitter)

Answer (score 1):

Its not possble to upload video on twitter. 
Possible approach is to upload video on some third party server and then share URL on twitter.

Check similar post by me long ago.
[Upload video on twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681924/upload-video-on-twitter)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link [Click here](https://github.com/Kovartthan/TwitterVideoShare) .....Twitter video share this may be useful to others . I have made up a library by extending twitter4j library . Note this is used for only Silent Video share i.e Without using the composer .