# uploading a video to twitter but getting error as Error creating status

Tags: android, api, video, twitter, twitter4j

I have successfully uploaded image to twitter. I am trying to upload a video to twitter but it is giving  Error creating status. I am using twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar. This is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey("HuxTZu8Cwc64RgpZIMfx3r8Kk");
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret("ZOSaJA6APCV8AuvXbrLuR6oyUEUL3YjvwPsyrrpYFVVFii4vjr");

        AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN", ""), pref.getString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", ""));
        Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            try {

                File file = new File(picturePath);
                StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(messageText.getText().toString());
                statusUpdate.setMedia(file);
                status = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
                if (status == null) { 
                    // don't know if needed - T4J docs are very bads
                    System.out.println("tweet null ------- ");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("tweet count ------- " + status.toString());
                }
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                System.err.print("Failed to search tweets: " + e.getMessage());
                // e.printStackTrace();
                // DON'T KNOW IF THIS IS THROWN WHEN ID IS INVALID
            }
            return status.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is the error i am getting

```
W/System.err: Failed to search tweets: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following). W/System.err: message - Error creating status. W/System.err: code - 189
```

Do i need to use twitter4j-media-support-4.0.4 for posting the videos?
Can anyone help me in fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: nobody is there to help me.

Comment: i am facing same issue i show [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681924/upload-video-on-twitter)

Comment: Hi ,
i also have the same issue. If you got solution Please help me to share video into twitter.@Nikhil PV

Comment: @gowthami i couldn't able to solve the issue.