# Share video from sd card to twitter in android

Tags: android, post, video, twitter, share

I have to upload video to twitter (post a tweet with video) from my android application. I use twitter4j to upload images and it works perfectly.This is my code to upload Image.I want to upload video from sd card to twitter. If any one knows the solution please help me.

```
       String status ="Check out this Tweak "+shareUrl;
        try {
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey);
            builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);

            // Access Token
            String access_token = prefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
            // Access Token Secret
            String access_token_secret = prefs.getString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, "");



            twitter4j.auth.AccessToken token = new twitter4j.auth.AccessToken(access_token,
                    access_token_secret);


            twitter4j.auth.AccessToken accessToken = new twitter4j.auth.AccessToken(access_token,
                    access_token_secret);
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

            // Update status
            StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(status);
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = new URL(ShowDialogforMore.twittImage).openStream();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            statusUpdate.setMedia("test.jpg",is);

            twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681924/upload-video-on-twitter

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my question. Here is my code. Now am able to share video to the twitter.

```
try {
                Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator + "Video" + File.separator + "Sample_nw.mp4";


                File f = new File(path);
                // String filename = "twitter_image.jpg";
                //  File imageFile = new File(getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename);
                String tweetUrl ="Tweak Video";

                // tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent., "good afternoon all");
                tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tweetUrl);
                tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
                tweetIntent.setType("video/*");


                PackageManager pm = activity.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
                List<ResolveInfo> lract = pm.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                boolean resolved = false;
                for (ResolveInfo ri : lract) {
                    if (ri.activityInfo.name.contains("twitter")) {


                        tweetIntent.setClassName(ri.activityInfo.packageName,
                                ri.activityInfo.name);
                        resolved = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                activity.startActivityForResult(resolved ?
                        tweetIntent :
                        Intent.createChooser(tweetIntent, "Choose one"), 110);

            } catch (final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            }
```